# Correct word translation: moving out of the country

Tags: english-to-german

I am moving out of the country and would like to inform my creditors of such. How do I correctly say that in German, "moving from Germany to US?".
When I tried to locate such information, I'm receiving a word regarding changing clos

Comment: You could say "Ich ziehe aus Deutschland in die USA". So the term you may be looking for is "umziehen" -> to move house, to relocate.

Comment: Well, the reason you recieve a word about changing of clothes is the fact that it is the correct word: Changing from your workout clothes to formal evening attire would be "umziehen", changing your place of residence (in any form really; even if you for instance merely switched from one side of the street to the other) would be "umziehen" as well. So "Ich ziehe um" would be correct if you move your place of residence. "Ich ziehe mich um" would be correct for changing clothes.

Answer (score 2):

You have different possibilities. They depend on the aspect of what you want to tell.

a) I agree with @Burki that "Ich **ziehe** aus [von] Deutschland in die USA" is decent. With this you express the **event of moving** your main place of residence from A to B. This says nothing about the intention, regarding to temporary or permanent movement.

b) Germans use also the phrase "Aus Deutschland [in die USA] **auswandern**". This stronger transports the aspect of **permanent (e)migration**, if this should be expressed.

There may be more decent translations. Will add more as they come to my head.

Comment: It should be noted that **auswandern** is used for leaving one's homeland, not for any moving out.